# Reverse Public/Private key Encryption?

Tags: security, authentication, encryption

Might be an unqualified question, but are there any encryption systems where two encryption keys are generated (one public, one private), and...

A) The public key is used for encrypting the information, but cannot be used to decrypt it
B) The private key is used for decrypting the information, and cannot be used to encrypt it.

I am asking because I see this as the only practical way to secure a login session to a web service (such as a forum) without the use of SSL/HTTPS.  Though, with my limited knowledge of system security and cryptography, it's more than likely that I'm wrong.

Comment: RSA with large `e` might be able to do that. But most likely your whole approach is flawed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common private key encryption algorithm is RSA. However, if you don't know what you're doing, stick to higher level constructs such as SSL/TLS.

Comment: Aye, I probably will be using SSL/TLS.